# Import workitems to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is is possible to import work items from excel or some other data source to TFS 2010?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the work item migrator: http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/.

Comment: I ended up writing a tool that does it.

Comment: Hi agris, what sort of tool did you write?  Database inserts, the tfs web service, TFPT command line?  Something else?  Thanks for any information you can give.

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  Create a Work Item Query in VS and then click "Export to Excel".  From there, you can add, edit, and delete work items that fit your query and click the "Publish" option in Excel under the "Team" menu.

Comment: See also "Connect a Microsoft Office Document to Team Foundation Server" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method was using a stored query from TFS while reviewing the data within Excel and publishing the new inputs back to TFS. This method works especially for those of you who can't seem to get people out of the habit of using Excel; which also works for bug tracking, project plans, team assignments, and everything else your company uses Excel to accomplish.

All you need to do is, create a DSN to your data source within ODBC / JDBC utility. Use the "Team" (TFS) tab integration w/in EXCEL. (Download it if you haven't already.) Run a stored or newly created query in Excel from the "Team" tab to TFS. Now all you have to do is get your data into the correct columns and you're done. To do that, copy-n-paste or map the fields w/in the Workbook/worksheet, of data you need to upload to TFS, and click the publish icon. Some fields, will be in read-only format so you can't update.modify data w/in those fields; but don't worry, once it's published back to TFS the system will handle all of those fields 'automajically' for you.

Once the update is complete........you're the man. Everyone loves you, for at least that moment in time, and you can move onto your next task.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly import the work items from Visual Studio using Power Tools.

You can download the tool from this site [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)

After you install the power tools you just need to start Visual Studio -> Tools -> Process Editor -> Work Item Types -> Import and then select the file(xml) and the collection where you want to import the work item type.

Comment: This will only import work item **types**, not actual work items